# LIKE with integers in PostgreeSQL using R

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, where-clause, sql-like

I need to download a table from postgree to R, but filtered by part of an INT.

I have been trying:

```r
library(RPostgreSQL)


con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), user= "#####", dbname="######",password="#####"  
                 ,host="#####", port='######')                         

vetor_id <- c("83052407","10406587","12272377")

match_id <- dbGetQuery(con,paste("
                                         SELECT *
                                         FROM public.data2015 
                                         WHERE  id IN ('", paste(vetor_id,collapse = "','"),"')
                                        ",sep = ""))

dbDisconnect(con)
```

I also tried  `CONTAINS` but didn't work.`WHERE  Contains(id,", paste(vetor_id,collapse = " OR "),"')`

`id` is INT and `vetor_id` is just part of the values. I mean,vector_id = 83052407 must find id = 83052407000132.

How can I use something like `LIKE` and put `vetor_id%` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE id::text like ? || '%'
```

This converts the integer `id` to a string, and attempts to match it against the parameter. If `id` *starts with* the parameter, the condition is satisfied.

Note that this uses a legitimate query parameter (represented by the question mark): you should get used to parameterize your queries rather than concatenating variables in the query string: this is cleaner, more efficient and safer.

Comment: Many thanks! But, I dont get how can I improve. I mean, in this example is just 3 values in the vector. But in my real data, I have lots of them.